# Python fast way to filter lines based on a list of keywords

Tags: python, algorithm, for-loop, indexing

I have a text file of many thousand lines which contain some String which at some position contains a unique identifer - and a List of identifers I want to filter for.

I want to extract all lines from this file which contain any identifier from my filter list. Currently I am solving this with two nested loops:

```py
    found = []
    for identifier in ids:
        with open("file.txt", 'r') as f:
            for line in f.readlines():
                if identifier in line:
                    found.append(line)
```

This however is extremely slow, as I run two nested loops and both the identifier list and the text file are huge. Is there a smart, more performant way in python to solve this in less than **O(n^2)**?

*Further infos & contraints:*

- Any line may only contain one or no identifers from my list
- I can't sort the file based on the identifers as they do not
  necessarily have a form that can be hieraricly structured

Comment: It would be better, adding sample of `ids` list, smoe text line of `file.txt` and output sample.

Comment: Reading the file again and again is most likely the bottleneck. -> read the file only once and check each line for each id.

Comment: You could construct a regexp to search for all keywords at once.

Answer (score 5):

Reordering the code should speed it up, such that you read the text file only once.

```
f = open("demofile.txt", "r")
mylines = f.readlines()
                       
found = []
for line in mylines:
   for identifier in ids:
      if identifier in line:
          found.append(line)
```

Comment: Good point! I did not even notice that I read it in each time.

Comment: Please accept the answer if it resolved your problem

Answer (score 3):

It's not clear how the `line` is composed, but if it can be tokenized cleanly, you could make the `identifier` collection a `set`, then check if the line's identifier is in the set.

`set` is a hashset, so its lookup is O(1), so the entire thing should run in O(n).

Using `readlines` also seems unnecessary, iterate on the file lazily.

```py
ids = set(ids)
with open('demofile.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    found = [
        line
        for line in f
        if get_id(line) in ids
    ]
```

you just need to provide `get_id`, which just slices out "a unique identifer" "at some position".

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend using https://pypi.org/project/triegex/ to build a regular expression that matches any of your identifiers and does a minimum of backtracking.

And now you just have a single loop.

Answer (score 1):

Your code will repeat some lines if the line contains more than one id.

So, Here we will try a different technique - I am not sure it will be faster or not - but it will grantee no repeating lines, and this technique based on a strong foundation.
Let us try using panads:

```
import pandas as pd 
ids=['id1', 'id2', 'id3'] # list of string ids
df=pd.read_csv('file.txt', sep = "`", names = ['txt'])
found =list(df.txt.loc[df.txt.apply(lambda x: sum((id in x) for id in ids )>0)])
```

*Some Clarification*

`` df=pd.read_csv('file.txt', sep = "`", names = ['txt']) `` Load the file into DataFrame. I used `` ` `` as a speratore to consider all the line as one column, since `` ` `` is rarely to be used in normal text lines.

`(id in x) for id in ids` generates a list of `True` and `False` based on how many exeistance of such ids in each line (row), and the outer `sum` will get summation of `True`

if we have a `file.txt`

```
fwpep poweripoi id1 ewlfdfkd f p[woer[pwe dlkdfwero0iopwiperew
we;rioepo ,r rtoipweorit ,rt rtopipowerit
werert.rtrtid1eyri  id1  id2 pid2oerit poier tpoerit eropitpo
```

so the found content will be:

```
Out[1]:found 
['fwpep poweripoi id1 ewlfdfkd f p[woer[pwe dlkdfwero0iopwiperew',
 'werert.rtrtid1eyri  id1  id2 pid2oerit poier tpoerit eropitpo']
```

meanwhile, your original code content will be

```
Out[1]:found 
['fwpep poweripoi id1 ewlfdfkd f p[woer[pwe dlkdfwero0iopwiperew',
 'werert.rtrtid1eyri  id1  id2 pid2oerit poier tpoerit eropitpo',
 'werert.rtrtid1eyri  id1  id2 pid2oerit poier tpoerit eropitpo']
```